# Удаление элементов из QListWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

Доброго времени суток.

Мне нужно как-то удалять элементы из QListWidget при нажатии на кнопку в добавляемом виджете.

Добавляемые виджеты выглядят вот так:

[image]

Добавляю такие виджеты вот таким вот способом:

```
//mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::on_addPlotButton_clicked() {
  QListWidgetItem *item = new QListWidgetItem(this->ui->plotInfoList);
  this->ui->plotInfoList->addItem (item);
  PlotInfoWidget *theItem = new PlotInfoWidget;
  item->setSizeHint (theItem->sizeHint ());
  this->ui->plotInfoList->setItemWidget (item, theItem);

}
```

Пытался удалять при нажатии на кнопку минус(скриншот) вот таким вот способом:

```
//plotinfowidget.cpp
void PlotInfoWidget::on_deleteButton_clicked()
{
    delete this;
}
```

Но при попытке добавить после этого новый элемент выдаёт такую ошибку

[image: Ошибка]

Можно добавить еще одну кнопку и удалять выбранные мышкой элементы, но хотелось бы чтоб они удалялись при помощи кнопки на самом виджете.

Прошу вашей помощи в реализации или подбрасывании идей, в Qt начал разбираться недавно так что хотелось бы получить максимально (насколько возможно) развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать красиво через сигнал из виджета строки.

Берем ваш специальный виджет для строки и добавляем в него сигнал типа "Убей меня":

```
class PlotInfoWidget: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PlotInfoWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr):... {
        connect(ui->closeButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &PlotInfoWidget::killMe);
    }
signals:
    // Тот самый сигнал
    void killMe();
    ...
}
```

Далее, так как этот виджет создан для того, чтобы быть виджетом строки списка, то непосредственно в нем мы создадим `QListWidgetItem`.

Добавим к предыдущему коду следующий функционал:

```
class PlotInfoWidget: public QWidget {
public:
    PlotInfoWidget(QWidget* parent):
        QWidget(parent), ui(...),
        _item(new QListWidgetItem()) {
    }
    
    ~PlotInfoWidget() {
        delete _item;
        delete ui;
    }

    QListWidgetItem* item() {
        _item->setSizeHint(this->sizeHint());
        return _item;
    }
private:
    QListWidgetItem* _item;
}
```

Здесь мы подразумеваем, что время жизни `QListWidgetItem` совпадает со временем жизни самого виджета `PlotInfoWidget`, поэтому он его порождает, он же его и удаляет (см. деструктор). Но перед тем как удалить итем, его надо вынуть из списка (в тот же момент, когда мы удаляем сам виджет строки, см. далее)

Теперь последнее - функция добавления (здесь же и удаление) виджета в список:

```
void MainWindow::on_addPlotButton_clicked() {
    // Создаем наш виджет
    PlotInfoWidget* widget = new PlotInfoWidget();

    // Добавляем итем в список
    ui->listWidget->addItem(widget->item());
    // виджет
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(widget->item(), widget);

    // Теперь соединяем сигнал удаления с функцией (можно 
    // сделать отдельную слот-функцию)
    connect(widget, &PlotInfoWidget::killMe, this, [&](){
        // Получаем виджет
        PlotInfoWidget* widget = qobject_cast<PlotInfoWidget*>(sender());
        
        if (widget) { // Если все ок
            // Где мы в списке?
            int row = ui->listWidget->row(widget->item());
            if (row > -1) {
                // Вынимаем из списка итем
                ui->listWidget->takeItem(row);
                // Удаляем виджет (точнее, помечаем на удаление), 
                // в котором, в деструкторе удалится итем
                widget->deleteLater();
            } else {
                // Хм...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Можно наследовать `QListWidget` и поместить всю эту красоту туда, чтобы не "засорять" основной код окна

Answer (score 1):

Ну, `delete this` вызывать нельзя никогда: как объект может удалить сам себя, если он в момент вызова занят работой одного из методов, в котором встретился такой вызов? Поэтому и Segmentation Fault. Удаление элементов из QListWidget делается так:

```
int deletee = ... // найти номер элемента для удаления
delete ui->listWidget->takeItem(deletee);
```

Comment: А как можно получить ui главного окна? У меня в PlotInfoWidget нету listWidget, он находиться в другом ui

Comment: примерно так: `dynamic_cast<MyMainWindow*>(this->parent)->ui`. Только QTCreator `ui` делает `private`, поэтому надо как-то вытащить наружу. Либо переместить в `public`, либо сделать методы, возвращающие нужные элементы управления.

Comment: попробывал сделать вот так вот: https://codeshare.io/5wAdx7 выдаёт ту же ошибку

Comment: По идее, так Вы всё равно получите segmentation fault, т.к. принципиально ничего не изменилось, Вы удаляете объект из его же метода. Я бы попробовал на родительском окне сделать метод, который запустит таймер и удалит нужный элемент управления с небольшой задержкой. Возможно, такого же эффекта можно достичь, если на Вашем `PlotInfoWidget` создать сигнал, а слот для него сделать на родителе, но я не помню синтаксис и не уверен, что прокатит.

Comment: Да уж, похоже прийдёться делать отдельную кнопку и удалять выбраный елемент, но спасибо что показали как можно получить родительский Ui

Comment: Не думаю, что то, что Вы хотите, невозможно сделать в QT. Может, кто-нибудь ещё чего-нибудь подскажет.